# When I should make sequence from lazy sequence

Tags: clojure

I'm reading [Programming Clojure](http://pragprog.com/book/shcloj2/programming-clojure) now and I find out next example

```
(defn by-pairs [coll]
  (let
    [take-pair (fn [c] (when (next c) (take 2 c)))]
    (lazy-seq
      (when-let [pair (seq (take-pair coll))] ;seq calls here
        (cons pair (by-pairs (rest coll)))))))
```

it breaks list into pairs, like

```
(println (by-pairs  [1 2 1]))     ((1 2) (2 1))
(println (by-pairs  [1 2 1 3]))   ((1 2) (2 1) (1 3))
(println (by-pairs  []))          ()
(println (by-pairs  [1]))         ()
```

What I can not get is why we should invoke seq on take-pair result? So why we can not just write

```
(defn by-pairs [coll]
  (let
    [take-pair (fn [c] (when (next c) (take 2 c)))]
    (lazy-seq
      (when-let [pair (take-pair coll)]
        (cons pair (by-pairs (rest coll)))))))
```

In witch cases there are will be different results or are there are any performance reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the code are same and there will be no difference because `next` and `take` functions that are being applied to coll in `take-pair` function, do call `seq` on the passed parameter i.e `next c` will first call `seq` on c or try to check if it is an object which implements `ISeq` and same in being doing by the `take` function. So basically in this case if you don't call `seq` yourself, the `next` and `take` will call `seq` on it.